# Postgresql not starting on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, postgresql

I just installed postgresql on ubuntu 16.04.1, but unfortunatly it won't start.

I installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

When running psql however I get an error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

As far as I can tell the server is not started, but I am unable to figure out why:

```
$ systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-12-20 19:49:02 UTC; 1h 6min ago
  Process: 1724 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1724 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Dec 20 19:49:02 ov-36271c systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Dec 20 19:49:02 ov-36271c systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

The output of pg_lsclusters:

```
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory Log file
```

I have tried uninstalling and installing again, but with the same effect.
Can somebody provide me a hint how to track down this issue and get postgresql running?

Thanks

Comment: What do you see if you type `pg_lsclusters`?

Comment: @darksky: nothing. This is the output:
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory Log file. I have updated the question with this info.

Comment: Do you see any error if you try to start it manually? `sudo pg_createcluster 9.5 main --start`

Comment: I have solved this by reinstalling ubuntu from scratch. I have done the same steps for installing postgresql, and now it works ... strange.
@darksky thanks for your help